# Isometries along the normalized Ricci flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, ricci-flow

As we know the Ricci flow preserves isometries of the initial manifold along the flow. But I want to know does the normalized Ricci flow preserves isometries of the initial manifold along the flow as well?
In my opinion the normalized ricci flow does not preserve isometries. Because if we consider the evolution equation for the normalized ricci flow, i.e. 
$$\partial_t g(t)=-2Ric(g(t))-\frac{2}{n}r_{g(t)}g(t),$$
where $$r=\frac{\int_M R\,dV_{g(t)}}{\int_M\,dV_{g(t)}},$$
is the average scalar curvature, we will observe that 
$$\partial_t (\phi^*g(t))=-2Ric(\phi^*g(t))-\frac{2}{n}r_{g(t)}(\phi^*g),$$
where $\phi:M\longrightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism.
Thus $r_{g(t)}$ does not change to $r_{\phi^*g(t)}$ under the pullback by $\phi$.

Am I right?

I will be grateful for any help or reference...

Comment: it preserves isometries.

Comment: May you pleases explain how it preserves isometries?

Comment: The second term is the same at all points --- it only rescales the metric; the same holds for any flow  $$\partial_t g=-2\cdot\mathrm{Ric}_{g}-g\cdot f(t),$$ for any $f$ that depends only on $t$.

Comment: Did you try to do the calculation? Try not to say “in my opinion”. In math, you know it’s true, or you know it’s false, or you don’t know. In the last case, it’s best not to express an opinion.

Comment: Maybe you are right; but I mean "in my knowledge". yes i did the calculation and i wrote it above.